# Is there a working maven pom for vaadin FancyLayouts addon?

Tags: maven, vaadin, pom.xml, add-on

I have decided to use a layout addon in my Vaadin project which is a `maven` project, but after taking the `maven pom` available on the addon page, it somehow fails to resolve from the maven repository.

Please can some tell me how to get a working maven pom or how I can get around this?

Here is the maven

```
<repository>
   <id>vaadin-addons</id>
   <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.vaadin.alump.fancylayouts</groupId>
   <artifactId>fancylayouts-addon</artifactId>
   <version>0.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: maybe is late now, but, did you add the maven vaadin repository to your pom?

Comment: Yes , i did add the exact maven as detailed on vaadin site.

Comment: i have attached the maven pom
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this addon work into your maven project layout, you need to download the project zip bundle from [github](https://github.com/alump/FancyLayouts/archive/master.zip).

Extract the zip content to any directory and cd into the addon folder:

```
unzip FancyLayouts-master.zip
cd FancyLayouts-master/fancylayouts-addon/
```

Once there, using your favorite text editor, change the first lines of the `pom.xml`. Replace the `<parent>...</parent>` tags along with its content with the `version` tag (althoug the addon page in the vaadin directory says that the addon version is `0.2.1` the project code version for the downloaded bundle is `0.3-SNAPSHOT`). The first 14 lines of the file should look like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.vaadin.alump.fancylayouts</groupId>
  <artifactId>fancylayouts-addon</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>FancyLayouts addon</name>
  <description>FancyLayouts Vaadin addon</description>
  <version>0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>  

  <organization>
      <name>Sami Viitanen</name>
      <url>http://vaadin.com/alump</url>
  </organization>
```

Build the addon using: `mvn install`

It should build successfully and install automatically into your local repository, to reference it from your project, add the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.vaadin.alump.fancylayouts</groupId>
       <artifactId>fancylayouts-addon</artifactId>
       <version>0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Explanation of the workaround:** If you try to install the addon using just `mvn install` and then reference the dependency in your `pom.xml`, maven will complain about not finding the parent pom for this library (something like: `Cannot find parent: org.vaadin.alump:fancylayouts for project`), thats why we have to delete the `parent` tag and rebuild the addon without it